# Configuring web application on jetty to use external logging config for logback

Tags: jetty, external, logback

I have a web application getting deployed on embedded jetty 9.2.3

I have tried externalising the logging libraries and config from the web app by doing the following:

- placed slf4j, logback-classic and logback-core libs under lib/logging
- placed logback.xml file under resources

However, this does not have the desired effect and the logs are appearing in the same manner as it was with default jetty configuration.

If I place logback.xml and the dependencies within the web app, the logs are appearing correctly.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded Jetty and Complex Logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026163/embedded-jetty-and-complex-logging)

Comment: See prior [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19033201/775715)